# WebView Automation Android - Capture Steps performed by the user & Repeat it automatically

Tags: android, android-webview, appium-android, webviewchromium, android-espresso-web

I need help to automate WebView, requirements

1. first **capture/record steps(NOT Video Record) performed by the user like Scroll, Entering credentials, Navigating to another webpage, or anything that a user could do.**
2. Then the WebView should be able to **repeat the same interaction with same time interval in each step till end.**

**Demo Video : [Without Compression](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uTvlmZKVWCjG_exQOdJFO19ZbX2DRH8x)**

1. [In then first video, I performed some random steps and the web view recorded the step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13oOc.gif)
2. [In the second video, I clicked on re-perform option and the app started performing the same steps till the end with exact time interval which I had in each step that i originally performed in the first video on its own/ automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNhHL.gif)

Also this has to be done on users device, so we **can't** use any other tool which requires USB or PC.

**Please suggest any library or any links that can help, because manually coding JS and then embedding it in Webview for every possible scenario is not feasible.**

I tried looking for similar apps online but found a app which had similar feature as a part of it.

I have never used **Appium** and also it required USB from user side, so i didn't even try it.

Need something which can manage to enter credentials, enter data, and automate all the actions performed by the user in webview.